# What rust std::collection datastructure are not supported on Solana

Tags: on-chain, datastructure

I remember there used to be this limitation that std::collection::Hashmap data structure was not supported and the solution was to use a pda, i just wanted to find information on all such possible data structures which are not allowed for e.g Hashset,btreeset,btreemap, can anyone clarify or point to any docs with this information ?